# Python - How to prevent variables from being lost during loop?

Tags: python

I'm currently three days in learning Python; Here's a pretty basic program from the book 'Automate the Boring Stuff with Python - Practical Programming for Total Beginners from Al Sweigarts', with some improvements from myself.

```
import random
import sys
#
def getAnswer(answerNumber):
 if answerNumber == 1:
    return 'no'
 elif answerNumber == 2:
    return 'yes'
#
print("Yes or no questions will be answerd. To end the program, enter 'exit'")
while True:
 resposta = input ()
 if resposta == 'exit':
  print ('goodbye')
  sys.exit()
 print(getAnswer(random.randint(1, 2)))
```

But it troubles me that every time the loop restarts the variables are lost, so if the same question is asked twice different answers can be given. How can i fix that? (I have tried using the global statement with no success)

Comment: The variables are lost?

Comment: What are you expecting to achieve?

Comment: you just use `getAnswer()` function with random number of 1 or 2. nothing get lost! just random answer and it can be 1 or 2 twice by random

Comment: @StephenRauch i might be using the wrong terminology, but what i'm trying to say is that the random number attributed is not retained, so if i input the same question twice i may get different answers, and i don't want this to happen.

Comment: @sophros I want to code so the program to always give me the same answer for the same input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want DO NOT want to display different outputs for the same question. This might help you.

I've added the question and it's answer to a history dictionary, so everytime a new question is entered, It's gets stored and when the same question is repeated, The answer WILL NOT change. Here's the code.

```
import random
import sys

history = {} # History Dictionary

def add_to_history(resposta, answer): # New addition
    history.update({resposta: answer})

def getAnswer(answerNumber):
 if answerNumber == 1:
    return 'no'
 elif answerNumber == 2:
    return 'yes'

print("Yes or no questions will be answerd. To end the program, enter 'exit'")

while True:

 resposta = input()
 if resposta == 'exit':
  print ('goodbye')
  sys.exit()

 # Check if the question has been answered before
 if resposta in history.keys():
     print("printing from history")
     print(history[resposta])
 # If not then create a new answer
 else:
     print("getting answer")
     answer = getAnswer(random.randint(1, 2))
     print(answer)
     add_to_history(resposta, answer)
```

Here's it in action.

```
Does the sun rise in the east?
getting answer
no
Did my program work?
getting answer
yes
Does the sun rise in the east?
printing from history
no
```